# SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature (Composer Error)

Tags: composer-php

my composer gives that error. I searched but i could not find anything.

Here is an image from error.

[composer_error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIPL9.png)

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature' in C:\ProgramData\Co
>   mposerSetup\bin\composer.phar on line 24
>   PharException: phar "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar on line 24
>   Call Stack:
>       0.0082     233920   1. {main}() C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:0
>       0.0084     234080   2. Phar::mapPhar() C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:24

Waiting for your suggestions..

Thanks.

Comment: Has it ever worked? It looks like your `composer.phar` file is corrupted… You may just have to delete it and install again.

Comment: It was working i dont know what happend, i removed it then reinstalled but still same error.

Comment: I reinstalled it, and used long path for composer file. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall composer from control panel and install it again.